# Why doesn't .count() correctly identify how many ")"'s are within a given string?

Tags: python-3.x

My goal is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once in the original string. And I'm ignoring capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

My code:

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    for i in word:
        if word.count(i) > 1:
            word = word.replace(i, ")")
        elif word.count(i) == 1:
            word = word.replace(i, "(")
    print(word)


duplicate_encode( "S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH(")
```

the above outputs: `))))))))))))))))))))))))))`
instead of the correct: `))())(()())))()((()())()((` 
so why does it count and replace the open parenthesis correctly and not the # closing parenthesis? and how can I make it work?

Comment: I simply copy pasted what the program that is asserting these strings into the function told me, I replaced the older one with another assert in order to hopefully make it make more sense. Also just realized that every time I post on this damn website something goes wrong. it butchered my formatting AGAIN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying `word` as you iterate over it, so after looking at the first character, `word` is now:

```
)))gqgyltcgfr(yul
```

So that third `)` is no longer unique by the time you get to it. Eventually you replace all the previous `(` with `)` A better approach might be to build a new string as you go:

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    res = ''
    for i in word:
        if word.count(i) > 1:
            res +=  ")"
        elif word.count(i) == 1:
            res += "("
    return res


print(duplicate_encode("S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH("))
```

**Result**

```
))())(()())))()((()())()((
```

Comment: This fixed my problem and kept my probably very crappy formatting! you are quite talented AND helpful! Thank you!

Comment: while it may not really matter this scales poorly... it calls `word.count` once or twice per character.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist totally agree  — it could be refactored for efficiency. I was hoping not add too much beyond the immediate question.

Comment: that is ofther the thing to decide: stay close to the original and point out problems or do it the way you would yourself. i usually can't help myself and go for the latter. but often the former approach is more helpful. happy pythoning!

Answer (score 1):

you replace `m` by `)` in the first iteration of the loop; `q` by `(` somewhat later on. then towards the end you relpace all `(` by `)` (including the parenthesis that are output strings and not input strings...).

this is my suggestion:

```
from collections import Counter

def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    counter = Counter(word)
    t_table = {char: ")" if i == 1 else "(" for char, i in counter.items()}
    return word.translate(str.maketrans(t_table))
```

which yields:

```
word = "mm)GQGylTcGFR(yul"
ret = duplicate_encode(word)
print(word) # mm)GQGylTcGFR(yul
print(ret)  # ))()()))(()((()()

word = "S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH("
ret = duplicate_encode(word)
print(word)  # S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH(
print(ret)   # ))())(()())))()((()())()((
```

using `str.translate` you avoid re-replacing characters you already have replaced.

note that it iterates once only over `word` to count the occurrences of the characters; then once in order to translate the characters. this implementation is very efficient (because most of the looping is delegated to a library).

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that count is not working correctly. Instead, the variable `word` is being while you are going through the loop, causing `if word.count(i) > 1:` to not be the same as `if "mm)GQGylTcGFR(yul".count(i) > 1:`, as you intended. Let's look at the output when we put in a print statement to see what's happening:

```py
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    for i in word:
        print(word)
        if word.count(i) > 1:
            word = word.replace(i, ")")
        elif word.count(i) == 1:
            word = word.replace(i, "(")
    print(word)


duplicate_encode("S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH(")
```

Output:

```
s@k@t)ayfssnvzygp!nwsvcth(
)@k@t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
))k)t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
))()t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
))()t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
))()))ayf))nvzygp!nw)vc)h(
))()))ayf))nvzygp!nw)vc)h(
))()))(yf))nvzygp!nw)vc)h(
))()))()f))nvz)gp!nw)vc)h(
))()))()())nvz)gp!nw)vc)h(
))()))()())nvz)gp!nw)vc)h(
))()))()())nvz)gp!nw)vc)h(
))()))()()))vz)gp!)w)vc)h(
))()))()())))z)gp!)w))c)h(
))()))()())))()gp!)w))c)h(
))()))()())))()gp!)w))c)h(
))()))()())))()(p!)w))c)h(
))()))()())))()((!)w))c)h(
))()))()())))()((()w))c)h(
))()))()())))()((()w))c)h(
))()))()())))()((()())c)h(
))()))()())))()((()())c)h(
))()))()())))()((()())c)h(
))()))()())))()((()())()h(
))()))()())))()((()())()h(
))()))()())))()((()())()((
))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

As you can see, you aren't actually counting the characters in the original string, but instead in the string with partially replaced characters.

An apparent solution is the following:

```py
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    result = word
    for i in word:
        if word.count(i) > 1:
            result = result.replace(i, ")")
        elif word.count(i) == 1:
            result = result.replace(i, "(")
    print(result)


duplicate_encode("S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH(")
```

Output:

```
((((((()((())()((()(()((((
```

Mmm, not quite right. Let's put in a print statement again:

```py
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    result = word
    for i in word:
        if word.count(i) > 1:
            result = result.replace(i, ")")
        elif word.count(i) == 1:
            result = result.replace(i, "(")
        print("After subbing for %s: %s" % (i, result))
    print(result)


duplicate_encode("S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH(")
```

Output:

```
After subbing for s: )@k@t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
After subbing for @: ))k)t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
After subbing for k: ))()t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
After subbing for @: ))()t)ayf))nvzygp!nw)vcth(
After subbing for t: ))()))ayf))nvzygp!nw)vc)h(
After subbing for ): ((((((ayf((nvzygp!nw(vc(h(
After subbing for a: (((((((yf((nvzygp!nw(vc(h(
After subbing for y: ((((((()f((nvz)gp!nw(vc(h(
After subbing for f: ((((((()(((nvz)gp!nw(vc(h(
After subbing for s: ((((((()(((nvz)gp!nw(vc(h(
After subbing for s: ((((((()(((nvz)gp!nw(vc(h(
After subbing for n: ((((((()((()vz)gp!)w(vc(h(
After subbing for v: ((((((()((())z)gp!)w()c(h(
After subbing for z: ((((((()((())()gp!)w()c(h(
After subbing for y: ((((((()((())()gp!)w()c(h(
After subbing for g: ((((((()((())()(p!)w()c(h(
After subbing for p: ((((((()((())()((!)w()c(h(
After subbing for !: ((((((()((())()((()w()c(h(
After subbing for n: ((((((()((())()((()w()c(h(
After subbing for w: ((((((()((())()((()(()c(h(
After subbing for s: ((((((()((())()((()(()c(h(
After subbing for v: ((((((()((())()((()(()c(h(
After subbing for c: ((((((()((())()((()(()((h(
After subbing for t: ((((((()((())()((()(()((h(
After subbing for h: ((((((()((())()((()(()((((
After subbing for (: ((((((()((())()((()(()((((
((((((()((())()((()(()((((
```

Aha, there's the issue. We sub for a parenthesis. Uh oh, looks like we need to approach the problem differently. Instead of replacing characters in the string, lets build a new one as we iterate through the string:

```py
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    result = ""
    for i in word:
        if word.count(i) > 1:
            result += ")"
        elif word.count(i) == 1:
            result += "("
    print(result)


duplicate_encode("S@k@T)ayFSSnvzyGP!nwSvcTH(")
```

Output:

```
))())(()())))()((()())()((
```

There we go!